# iOS 7 Xcode 5.1.1 Storyboard elements become invisible after editing

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a weird issue with my iOS7 and Xcode 5.1.1 storyboard of late.

Whenever I drag any element (Ex: `UIButton` or `UILabel`) and double click on it to change the text on the label or button and hit enter or click outside than that element disappears completely. I have to select that element again and check/uncheck the opaque option to make it visible again. This is very irritating.

I have tried searching the web but haven't found anything close to this.

Comment: "Please help me ASAP." I was with you until then.

Comment: `opaque` would have nothing to do with this. It's just a hint to the drawing engine at runtime; it does nothing whatever in the storyboard editor.

Comment: Choose Editor > Canvas > Show Layout Rectangles. This makes it clearer where things are.